# How do i combine a HTML Select with a Switch statement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I want to create a 'Sort By' List in which whatever list item is selected then my laravel php switch statement will come back with the correct query.. How do i do this?

So far i have

```
<select class="form-control" name="SortbyList" >
    <option value="1">Highest Avg</option>
    <option value="2">Lowest Avg</option>
    <option value="3">Another Sort option</option>
    <option value="2">another sort option</option>
</select>
```

How do i use this with a switch which will be place in my Laravel Controller?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't show any code, I'll give you a simple example:

```
$data = Model::query();

switch (request()->sortByList) {
    case 1:
        $data = $data->orderBy('average', 'desc');
        break;
    case 2:
        $data = $data->orderBy('average', 'asc');
        break;
    ...
}

$data = $data->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have all this but nothing seems to happen in terms of the select and switch? here is all the code i have...

```
            <select class="form-control" name="SortbyList" >
                <option value="1">Highest Avg</option>
                <option value="2">Lowest Avg</option>
                <option value="3">Another Sort option</option>
                <option value="2">another sort option</option>
            </select>
```

And controller:

```
 $productsQuery = Product::where('approved', '=', 1)->leftJoin('reviews', 'reviews.products_id', '=', 'products.id')->select('products.*', DB::raw('AVG(ratings) as ratings_average' ))->groupBy('products.id');
        switch ($request->SortbyList) {
            case 1:
                $productsQuery = $productsQuery->orderBy('ratings_average', 'DESC');
                break;
            case 2:
                $productsQuery = $productsQuery->orderBy('ratings_average', 'ASC');
                break;
            case 3:
                $productsQuery = $productsQuery->orderBy('ratings_average', 'ASC');
                break;
            case 4:
                $productsQuery = $productsQuery->orderBy('ratings_average', 'ASC');
                break;
                default:
                    $productsQuery = $productsQuery->orderBy('ratings_average', 'DESC');


        }



        $name=$request->input('productname');
        $count=$request->input('country_id');


        if(!empty($name)){
            $productsQuery->where('productname', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%')->get();
        }
        if(!empty($count)){
            $ProductsQuery->where('country_id', $request->input('country_id') )->get();
        }
        $products= $ProductsQuery->paginate(10);
```

Excuse case 3 and 4 im yet to code them.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to process the Sorting with PHP, you can do this on the client side, with JS/jQuery. This will do all work without refreshing the page.

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

jQuery(".form-control").change(function(){
var conceptName = jQuery('#link').find(":selected").text();

if(conceptName == "Highest Avg"){
   //sorting code here for highest
} 
if(conceptName == "Lowest Avg"){
   // code here
}
if(conceptName == "Another Sort option"){
   // code here
}


});
});
</script>
```